# How to create disk partition inside a Docker container on Windows server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

I am on Windows server 2016 Datacenter Evaluation and using Docker for Windows Community Edition version 17.05.0-

I have created few images through docker file and also through docker commands and I am trying to install MSSQL server inside container.
My MSSQL installation files are such that it automatically creates few folders on **D drive** but when I see inside container there is only **C drive** available.

Is there a way to perform disk partition inside containers?
I tried with diskpart command but it didn't work or is there way I can mount folders in D drive on my host machine on to containers ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not fully answer, but if I were you I would just be using the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows/) rather than install a custom version.  Is there a reason you don't want to?